# Set-valued map (measurability)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, multisets

I have this  exercice and i want to know how to solve it :

1)- Let $X,Y$ two separable metric spaces ,let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space ,and $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ a measurable function and $\varphi :\Omega \times X \rightarrow Y$ a Cartheodory function ,then the map: $\Omega\rightarrow Y$,
$x\mapsto \varphi (x,f(x))$ is measurable .

please; 
i don't know how to start .

Comment: Look the book" fundamentals of applied functional analysis" authors : Dragisa Mitrovic and darko zubrinic . look at the page 57 . in this page have a theorem and this theorem is a particular case of your question . maybe the proof apresented there can help ( my english is terrible, sorry... )

Comment: look the proof of the lemma 4.52 of this book : http://books.google.com.br/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=caratheodory+function&source=bl&ots=p9rOZui0Ov&sig=8onDzkzO2Znw1WtDJ7rUFd9IIok&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=MOUqUfa6M8a40QG7zYCQDg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=caratheodory%20function&f=false            maybe can help